# Removing the extra space from Top of BottomSheet

Tags: android, android-layout

I added bottomsheet in my application.ii work good but only problem is extra space it cover and I just want to remove those extra spaces on the top of Bottomsheet layout.

I want to remove the highlighted part:

[image]

How I can remove those extra spaces?

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/five"
                android:padding="@dimen/ten"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fifty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/five"
                android:padding="@dimen/ten"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_image_gallery"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fifty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/five"
                android:padding="@dimen/ten"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_video_camera"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fifty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/five"
                android:padding="@dimen/ten"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_video"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fifty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my Java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
    View bottomSheet;
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

        bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                // React to state change
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                // React to dragging events
            }
        });


        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
        });
    }

//        Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,item + " is selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
//        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (behavior.getState()==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {

                Rect outRect = new Rect();
                bottomSheet.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);

                if(!outRect.contains((int)ev.getRawX(), (int)ev.getRawY()))
                    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the top margin/padding from your BottomSheet or give it a negative value.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have got the answer. Just need to remove the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from bottom_sheet i.e the LinearLayout.
Just in case I am putting the xml code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/five"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fifty"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/five"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image_gallery"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fifty"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/five"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_video_camera"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fifty"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/five"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_video_camera"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fifty"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Just for my use, I have used different drawable you need to change it back to the original one.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was moving `android:layout-behaviour` from the `LinearLayout` to the `coordinatorLayout`. Or just removing it all together.

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

Will work!